# IntelliJ IDEA unable to resolve Maven dependencies on virtual machine

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I copied existing `Java` project to a virtual machine. There is same version of `IntelliJ IDEA` installed on both machines:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6
Build #IC-172.4574.11, built on November 13, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

I used `Maven` reimport on project, it seems successful, but dependencies are not resolved, so build fails. It is working without any error on other machine.
It seems `IntelliJ IDEA` doesn't execute on virtual machine, process is ended in a few seconds. I tried to pull project from repository on this machine instead of copying it, but there is same problem.

`maven-compiler-plugin` version is 1.7.

Comment: How do you know, that dependencies are not resolved? Which dependencies are not resolved? How does your `settings.xml` look like (if you have one)? Does the VM have internet access?

Comment: Dependencies are not resolved, because build failed and point to methods, which doesn't exist. I can't find `settings.xml` file. Yes, it has internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Check internet connection on your virtual machine, may be there are some issues there.
2 Check `settings.xml` file which is placed on `.m2` folder, may be there are setting to watch on another server. See documentation [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview)
3 Try to pull source code from repository in another folder.

Comment: I checked already Point 1 and 3.
What kind of setting do you think about?

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reuse projects across machines.  Create a fresh checkout and open IntelliJ again on the pristine project.